# Meaning of yywrap() in flex

Tags: gcc, compiler-construction, compilation, flex-lexer, lexical-analysis

What does this instructions mean in flex (lex) :

`#define yywrap() 1`

and this [ \t]+$
i find it in the code below:

(`%%
[ \t]+ putchar('_');
[ \t]+%
%%`

input "hello world"

output "hello_world"

)

Answer (score 18):

According to [The Lex & Yacc Page](http://dinosaur.compilertools.net/flex/flex_10.html) :

> When the scanner receives an end-of-file indication from **`YY_INPUT`**, it then checks the `yywrap()` function. If `yywrap()` returns false (zero), then it is assumed that the function has gone ahead and set up `yyin` to point to another input file, and scanning continues. If it returns true (non-zero), then the scanner terminates, returning 0 to its caller. Note that in either case, the start condition remains unchanged; it does not revert to **`INITIAL`**.

The `#define` is used to simplify building the program (so that no `-ll` linkage option is needed).

Further reading:

- [What are lex and yacc?](http://aquamentus.com/tut_lexyacc.html)
- [Routines to reprocess input](http://osr507doc.sco.com/en/tools/Lex_reprocessing.html)
- [6. How do Lex and YACC work internally](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Lex-YACC-HOWTO-6.html) (Lex and YACC primer/HOWTO)