# What happens if `yywrap()` does nothing?

Tags: c, parsing, compiler-construction, lex

I read that it's mandotary to write `%noyywrap` or define a `yywrap()` function.

What if I default a `yywrap()` function in which I don't make any changes to `yyin` variable and return 0, what will happen in this case?

0 means that FLEX should must continue parsing other input files but does flex insert null inside `yyin` variable one it's done parsing it or in this case it goes for infinite loop?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Meaning of yywrap() in flex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34479903/meaning-of-yywrap-in-flex)

Comment: @TedLyngmo not at all... I know that's the meaning of yywrap() and that's not my question... I have very specific question. does yyin get null value after finishing reading current file or we go in loop?

Comment: @Algo: you could easily test whether `yyin` is set to null by testing and/or printing in `yywrap`.

Answer (score 4):

If `yywrap()` returns 0, then the lexer will just loop (trying to) read more data.  If you're using the default `YY_INPUT` that reads from `yyin`, and you haven't changed it or called `clearerr` on it, you'll get an infinite loop.  If you call `clearerr`, then it will try to read more, but if `yyin` points at a file that hasn't changed, that will just be EOF again, and you'll still get an infinite loop.

If you've changed `YY_INPUT` to do something else that it will do whatever you've changed it to do.